# Argument list too long for xargs/exec

Tags: linux, bash, find, xargs, exec

I'm working on a CentOS server and I have to move around and cat together millions of files. I've tried many incarnations of something like the below, but all of them fail with an argument list too long error.

command:

```
find ./ -iname out.* -type f -exec mv {} /home/user/trash
find ./paramsFile.* -exec cat > parameters.txt
```

error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long
-bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long
```

or

```
echo ./out.* | xargs -I '{}' mv /home/user/trash
(echo ./paramsFile.* | xargs cat) > parameters.txt
```

error:

```
xargs: argument line too long
xargs: argument line too long
```

The second command also never finished. I've heard some things about globbing, but I'm not sure I understand it completely. Any hints or suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple mistakes. You should escape the `*` globbing. You have to put `{}` between quotes (for filename security), and you have to end the `-exec` with `\;`.

```
find ./ -iname out.\* -type f -exec mv "{}" /home/user/trash \;
find -name ./paramsFile.\* -exec cat "{}" >> parameters.txt \;
```

The problem here is that `*` is matching all the files in your directory, thus giving you the error. If `find` locates the files instead of shell globbing, `xargs` gets individual filenames that it can use to construct lines of the correct length.

Comment: You don't have to put `{}` between quotes for filename security! Without quotes is perfect unless your shell does weird stuff with it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find . -iname 'out.*' -type f -exec mv '{}' /home/user/trash \;
find . -name 'paramsFile.*' -print0 | xargs -0 cat >> parameters.txt
```

The `>>` is to make sure multiple invocations of `cat` (if you really have a huge number of files) output to the same file, without overwriting the result from previous calls. Also, make sure `parameters.txt` starts out empty (or delete it first).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems to still be too long for find and cat.

Comment: Oh, I guess I didn't really read that carefully. I updated the answer with the other call. Also, +1 to @Bernhard for bringing up some good points that I forgot about.

Comment: It's great that the reason for the >> is given, but it's wrong.  The redirection happens once, in the parent shell, regardless of how many times cat is invoked by xargs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a box handy at the moment to give a very good (ie, tested) answer, but I think this is a good use for [`parallel`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel/).

If I understand right, your command

```
find ./ -iname out.* -type f -exec mv "{}" /home/user/trash
```

is making one huge command:

```
mv out.1 out.2 out.3 out.4 ... out.10100942 /home/user/trash
```

Instead, something like

```
find ./ -iname out.* -type f | parallel mv "{}" /home/user/trash
```

will execute millions of smaller commands:

```
mv out.1 /home/user/trash
mv out.2 /home/user/trash
...
```

You might want to look into some of `parallel`'s options, specifically [`-j` and `-i`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel) so you don't unexpectedly overload your server.

PS. Follow @Bernhard's advice, whenever you use a shell variable, especially for user input, quote it! Do `"{}"` not `{}`.